# Do I use Javascript for HTML <select> needs to affect two variables?

Tags: javascript, html, paypal, forms, html-input

I'm currently working on a paypal checkout form.  The form allows the user to specify a few options and when they submit the form, it submits the order to paypal for processing.

The form has a `<select>` droplist that allows a user to select how many times they want a subscription to recur.  It is set up like this:

```
<select name="srt">                         <!-- User specifies amount of times payment should recur -->
    <option value="1"></option>
    <option value="2"></option>  
    <option value="3"></option>  
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">   <!-- Specifies that payment should be recurring-->
```

This works in most cases, however when the user selects the first option with the `srt` `value="1"`, paypal instead wants this to be submitted with `srt` blank or omitted and `src` (the hidden input below the form) with `value="0"`.  The reason for this seems to be that if the payment is to recur 1 time, meaning to charge the customer only once, then this is not a recurring payment at all, so `srt` is not valid and instead `src`, which specifies if payments should recur or not, should be set to `0`.

I'm wondering what is the best way to handle this.  The only thing I can think of is to use javascript to set hidden form values depending on what the user selects in a `<select>` drop list.

Is that the best way to handle this, or is there a better way that does not require the browser to handle javascript?

Thanks!

Comment: It's considered **PURE EVIL** to use hidden inputs as payment calculations, as an attacker can easily change them to show `0.00` before submitting. You should calculate that on the server side alone.

Comment: If the `src` value is being used instead of `srt`, something is very wrong with the submission process. Modifying the value of the hidden field may be a work-around, but you should investigate what has broken to require this.

Comment: @Rikudo Sennin - The form comes from my server, but submits and re-directs to paypal.  How else would I submit this information to paypal then?  Can I submit the form back to my server, then redirect to paypal?

I believe paypal has a mechanism to check form input to make sure it is congruent with valid prices.

Comment: @George Cummins - I agree its not optimal, its what paypal requires though, I wouldn't be in a position to fix it.

Comment: DutrowLLC: That's not really true. PayPal *allows* it, but it definitely doesn't require it. (BMCreateButton is an okay alternative. Even better is Express Checkout Recurring Payments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would like to make it clear that all values computed in the browser **must** be validated on the server. There really is **no substitute** for server side validation. Client-side scripts must only be used to improve user experience. **Failing to do so is a security hole waiting to be exploited.**

1. To solve the issue at hand you could exploit the fact that disabled inputs aren't submitted when a form is posted. Thus if the user doesn't select to make a recurring payment `srt` will never get posted.
2. Start out with `srt` both disabled and hidden.
3. The hidden input `src` should have a value of `0` to start with.
4. Add a "Recurring Payment?" checkbox to the form.
5. If the user selects the checkbox, enable and show `srt` via Javascript.
6. Set the value of `src` equal to whatever the user selects in `srt`.
7. Disable and blank out `srt` and `src` if the user ever unchecks the checkbox.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/EMT54/)

Markup:

```
<p><input type="checkbox" value="recurring" id="recurring"/>Recurring Payment?</p>
<select disabled id="srt" name="srt">                         
    <option selected value="2">2</option>  
    <option value="3">3</option>  
</select>
<input type="hidden" id="src" name="src" value="0">
```

jQuery:

```
$('#recurring').click(function() {
    var $srt = $('#srt'),
        $src = $('#src');
    if (this.checked) {
        $srt.prop('disabled', false).toggle();
        $src.val($srt.val());
    } else {
        $srt.prop('disabled', true).toggle();
        $src.val(0);
    }
});

$('#srt').change(function() {
    $('#src').val($(this).val());
});
```